# How to iterate over items one by one on a dataframe?

Tags: python, loops, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have following dataframe:

```
                                         Date   Price
Equity(231 [IBM])   2016-05-10 00:00:00+00:00  150.04
Equity(2574 [TSLA]) 2016-04-29 00:00:00+00:00  248.43
```

I tried iterating over dataframe using:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    print("symbol :\n",row[0])
    print("Date :\n",row[1])
    print("Price :\n",row[2])
```

Output:

```
symbol : Equity(231 [IBM])
Date : 2016-05-10 00:00:00+00:00
Price : 150.04
symbol : Equity(2574 [TSLA])
Date : 2016-04-29 00:00:00+00:00
Price : 248.43
```

I dont want the above output, because it iterates over both the IBM and TSLA instead of IBM alone.
I want the following output when we iterate:

```
Out:

symbol : Equity(231 [IBM])
Date : 2016-05-10 00:00:00+00:00
Price : 150.04
```

and upon next iteration:

```
Out:

symbol : Equity(2574 [TSLA])
Date : 2016-04-29 00:00:00+00:00
Price : 248.43
```

If you still find it difficult to understand, feel free to ask for more clarifications.

Comment: You've used a for loop, it will iterate over all the df.rows(available as tuples) until the last row and then ends(i mean comes out of loop). First check if you really need a for loop or any kind of conditional access to your dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) or [`DataFrame.iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    print("symbol :",row.Index)
    print("Date :",row.Date)
    print("Price :",row.Price)
    print ('***************************'

symbol : Equity(231 [IBM]))
Date : 2016-05-10 00:00:00+00:00
Price : 150.04
***************************
symbol : Equity(2574 [TSLA])
Date : 2016-04-29 00:00:00+00:00
Price : 248.43
***************************
```

---

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    print("symbol :",idx)
    print("Date :",row.Date)
    print("Price :",row.Price)
    print ('***************************')

symbol : Equity(231 [IBM])
Date : 2016-05-10 00:00:00+00:00
Price : 150.04
***************************
symbol : Equity(2574 [TSLA])
Date : 2016-04-29 00:00:00+00:00
Price : 248.43
***************************
```

Comment: i just want `IBM`s properties at first iteration and `TSLA` on 2nd iteration :)

Comment: That should be what you're getting in the code you've written.

Comment: @ArJuN - answer was edited, if necessary you can rewrite index by symbol by `df.index = df.index.str.extract('\[(.*)\]', expand=False)`

Comment: Are you after an alternative? or you want to create and  call a function manually so it goes after things based on count ?

Comment: @jezrael bro, in your output, both the IBM and TSLA are present at once, i want one at a time, thats what i want, is is possible?

Comment: @Bharathshetty i can look for alternative, note that i want `symbol`, `date`, `price` of each row and perform operations on each stock, once performed operation, iterate again and pick next stock i.e. `TSLA` and perform operation over `symbol`, `Date`, `Price`, i have lots of columns, so keep that in mind.

Comment: @ArJuN - Sorry, I dont understand. this 2 method loop datafarmes by rows. First iteration first row, second second row, N iteration N row. So what means present only once? I see your 2 rows and data and there are present once :(

Comment: @ArJuN Dude if you specify the operation you want to perform that would be really helpful. Or you can use `.apply` by creating a function. If you are in pandas its not a good idea to use a for loop. Good luck

Comment: @Bharathshetty i want to use those value to insert it into another function i.e. y_intercept(x, y, idx_last, context) , since the function is complicated (uses np.polyfit() and finds y itercept) i cant bypass for loop.

Comment: I dont understrand, why your original solution does not works? Why my original solutions does not work?

Comment: @jezrael Because it returns both rows at once, i want only one row upon each iteration, i.e. only `IBM` row :p

Comment: It does not return both rows at once. It returns one after the other. Call the function after the last print statement. When you print the data it appears to be two rows, practically they are returned one after the other. You got a lot to learn about loops.

Comment: @jezrael  Sorry, for troubling you, actually, i havent used for loop on tuples before, so that made me confuse a bit, i feel humiliated now :(

Comment: @Bharathshetty you caught me, i was confused on how for loop actually loops over tuples especially, and that made me confused, thanks for pointing it out, and am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet Sure, what exactly you want, but try below..

```
for idx in range(len(df)):
    desired_row = df.ix[idx]  #gets first row for 1st iteration as a series
    print(desired_row) ###you can call any function as per requirement here.
```

I can see nothing wrong with your trial or in @Jezrael's Answer, if you want to iterate over dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it raises `TypeError: 'DataFrame' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`.

Comment: Good one, all the answers posted are correct, but it was my mistake to not understand how `for loop` works on tuples, thus this confusion, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

What if you tried `iterrows`?

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print("symbol :\n",row[0])
    print("Date :\n",row[1])
    print("Price :\n",row[2])
```

Comment: `IndexError: index out of bounds`